# end of line (GNU documentation)

Tags: c, gcc

I'm reading documentation about gcc preprocessing, I read the following sentence ([here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Initial-processing.html#Initial-processing)):

> If the last line of any input file lacks an end-of-line marker, the end of the file is considered to implicitly supply one. The C standard says that this condition provokes undefined behavior, so GCC will emit a warning message.

I try to produce the warning by doing :

```
> echo -n "int main(void) {return 0;}" > test.c
> gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror test.c
```

But no prob, it compiles. I understand end-of-line marker as new-line char, but it seems to be anything else.

How could I produce the warning ?

Comment: `gcc -W`. Why would you *ever* run GCC without warnings...

Comment: Probably nobody cares about this situation.

Comment: @KerrekSB that is true, but using `-W` or `-Wall` on his example still doesn't yield the documented warning he's describing. At least not with `gcc` version 4.7.2.

Comment: neither `-pedantic`. So I stand by my first comment

Comment: @bolov if the C standard says that the lack of a trailing end of line character could "provoke" undefined behavior, wouldn't one care, at least a little (:)), if they were concerned about portability and inadvertently had that condition in their file?

Comment: @lurker Ok, yes, maybe a little you would care if you want to create truly portable code. But even then, you are never compiling against a theoretical ideal compiler. You compile against software implementations of the standard. Compilers not standard conformant,  compilers with bugs. So if you are truly interested in portable code (code that actually runs against as many compilers on as many platforms) I would still say that a new line before the end of file is pretty low on your priority. I would actually be surprised of a real world compiler that doesn't handle correctly this situation.

Comment: ... even then, the fix is so easy on the client part: add a new line. It can be even automated if it's a problem with multiple files.

Comment: @bolov: If you include two files, one ending in a comment witout EOL, the first line of the second file is accidentally commened out. Did you try this wiith a compiler? Did he handle the situation correctly?

Comment: @bolov it's perhaps a trivial issue. But the OP is asking about an apparent discrepancy between the GCC documentation and the actual behavior of the GCC compiler.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that it got removed from gcc.

See this:
https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=14331#c19

> 2007-05-31
>
> ```
>     PR preprocessor/14331
>     * lex.c (_cpp_get_fresh_line):  Don't warn if no newline at EOF.
> ```

Comment: Originally the warning was going to be made optional. The final patch removes it unconditionally. Since the behavior is undefined, I would have preferred to have an option to enable the warning.

Comment: You still (GCC 5.3.0) get a warning (convertible to error with `-Werror`) for: `min.c:1:29: warning: backslash-newline at end of file` for a file ending with backslash-newline.  If you have backslash with no newline, you get `min.c:1:1: error: stray ‘\’ in program` (unconditionally an error).  If you have backslash-newline-newline at the end, there's no problem (no error, or cause for giving one).

Comment: The C standard says in §5.1.1.2 Phases of Translation, ¶2 _Each instance of a backslash character (`\\`) immediately followed by a new-line character is deleted, splicing physical source lines to form logical source lines. Only the last backslash on any physical source line shall be eligible for being part of such a splice. A source file that is not empty shall end in a new-line character, which shall not be immediately preceded by a backslash character before any such splicing takes place._

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Yes, but the question wasn't about backslashes.

Comment: @KeithThompson: That section of the standard also covers newlines (they're needed).  And, as a special case, covers newlines preceded by backslashes.

Answer (score 1):

**C11(N1570), §5.1.1.2,** states:

> A source file that is not empty shall end in a new-line character,
> which shall not be immediately preceded by a backslash character
> before any such splicing takes place.

So not having a newline at the of the file violates the above "shall" constraint.

`clang` does warn about it:

```
$ printf "int main(void) {return 0;}" > test.c
$ clang -Weverything test.c
test.c:1:27: warning: no newline at end of file [-Wnewline-eof]
int main(void) {return 0;}
                          ^
1 warning generated.
```

But a constraint violation is [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

**C11(N1570), §4,** states:

> If a ‘‘shall’’ or ‘‘shall not’’ requirement that appears outside of a
> constraint or runtime constraint is violated, the behavior is
> undefined. Undefined behavior is otherwise indicated in this
> International Standard by the words ‘‘undefined behavior’’ or by the
> omission of any explicit definition of behavior. There is no
> difference in emphasis among these three; they all describe ‘‘behavior
> that is undefined’’.

So gcc took the liberty to take out the warnings (as noted by @nnn) as gcc is *not required* to issue any diagnostic for undefined behaviour.